# Aspect ratio of some of the images in my image gallery is wrong

Tags: html, css

I have an image gallery with many images , but some of them are with wrong aspect ratio. 
One is upside down - which is with width 4608 -3465 height .
The others are flipped right or left with ( w3024 - h4032) . Of course there are others that are displayed correctly( most are , i have about 5 images that are with wrong aspect ration)

html:

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img id="image_id_001" alt=" " src="Photos/_DSC0150.jpg">
      <p>Hotel</p>
     </div>
     <div class="imgBox">
      <img id="Fruit_Tree" alt=" " src="Photos/_DSC0226.jpg">
      <p>Fruit Tree</p>
     </div>
     <div class="imgBox">
      <img id="image_id_001" alt=" " src="Photos/_DSC0150.jpg">
      <p>Hotel</p>
     </div>
     <div class="imgBox">
      <img id="Fruit_Tree" alt=" " src="Photos/_DSC0226.jpg">
      <p>Fruit Tree</p>
     </div>
     <div class="imgBox">
      <img id="image_id_001" alt=" " src="Photos/_DSC0150.jpg">
      <p>Hotel</p>
     </div>
     <div class="imgBox">
      <img id="Fruit_Tree" alt=" " src="Photos/_DSC0226.jpg">
      <p>Fruit Tree</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#imageContainer img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imgBox{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

I tried with `object-fit` , but it does not work . 
Tried with `width:100%` and `height:100%` , still nothing .

I am not using Bootstrap, nor do i want to use it. Just plain html and css, as those are the ruquirements of the projec. Is there a possible solution ?

Comment: If you want the images to keep their aspect ratio you should specify only one dimension i.e. either width or height, and to stop the image from growing too large, set constraints via max width and max height

Answer (score 0):

To keep proportions try

```css
img {
  width:90%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Does not work , that way , every image is witth different height , and i do not want that, but either way the specific images are still reversed or rotated

Comment: Even if i load the one of the roatated images in aseparate html , with `width:90%;` and `height:auto;` , still they are rotated.

Comment: I'd blame the images

Comment: Is it possible to add a css property ( `portrait` or `landscape` ) to my JSON file , where all the images are stored ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for Firefox : 
Setting css property on the image:

`image-orientation: from-image;`

But this is not supported property in Chrome . 
So for Chrome there is another way to do it : 
With EXIF.js

```
EXIF.getData(this, function() {
let orientation;
orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation"){
                  if(orientation === 3) {
                      modalContent.css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
                   }
                  if(orientation === 6) {
                      modalContent.css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");

                   }
                  if(orientation === 8) {
                     modalContent.css("transform", "rotate(270deg)");
                   }
              })
```